# How to logout using link (HTTP GET) in Blazor and .NET 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

In the previous version of Blazor I could use:

```
await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/logout");
```

Now, I have to use:

```
Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
```

But the following code redirects me to Not found. Should I create a page "authentication/logout" or what?

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private void BeginLogOut()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

[image]

There is no single example anywhere :/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a form with a logout button which looks like a link :) hehe
The problem solved :)

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
            <AntiforgeryToken />
            <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="" />
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">
                Log out
            </button>
        </form>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```